# C# HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert() Not holding cached value

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm trying to cache a price value using HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(), but only appears to hold the value for a couple hours or something before clearing it out. What am I doing wrong?  I want the value to stay in cache for 3 days.

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(CacheName, Price, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Comment: How do you verify that it's cleared out?

Comment: @J.W. : Cache[CacheName] will be null if the entry has been removed / expired.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Short answer

Your application pool or website is being shutdown too soon. Extend the idle timeout on the site, extend the application pool lifetime for the pool running the site. Raise the memory allocation and request limits.

## Full answer

If you want to know when and why something is being removed from the cache, you need to log the item removal using the [CacheItemRemovedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback.aspx) option on the insertion... Then you can log the reason using the [CacheItemRemovedReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedreason.aspx) argument.  You can thus log the reason as one of the four listed reasons:

1. **Removed** The item is removed from the cache by a Remove method call or by an Insert method call that specified the same key.
2. **Expired** The item is removed from the cache because it expired.
3. **Underused**   The item is removed from the cache because the system removed it to free memory.
4. **DependencyChanged**   The item is removed from the cache because the cache dependency associated with it changed.

Typically, you will find Expired and Underused being the reasons for things that don't have explict Remove calls made against the cache and don't have dependencies.

You will likely find out, while tracing through this fun stuff, that your items are not being expired or underused. Rather, I suspect you'll find that the AppDomain is getting unloaded.

One way this can happen due to the web.config (or bin directory, or .aspx, etc.) files getting changed. For more information as to when this occurs see the **Application Restarts** section of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx). When that happens, the currently pending requests are drained, the cache emptied, and the AppDomain unloaded. You can detect this situation by checking the [AppDomain.IsFinalizingForUnload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.isfinalizingforunload.aspx) and logging that during the callback.

Another reason for the AppDomain to recycle is when IIS decides to recycle the AppPool for any of the reasons it has been configured with. Examples of that are *xxx* memory has been allocated over the lifetime, *yyy* seconds of runtime for the AppPool, *ttt* scheduled recycle time, or *iiii* idle time (no requests incoming). For further details check [this article for IIS6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720391(VS.71).aspx) or [this article for IIS7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347496.aspx)

Comment: I had this problem and couldn't get iis express to stop restarting the application, weirdly this was only a problem for mvc projects. I upgraded to full iis and the problem went away.

Comment: Great answer and a great username!

Comment: This has been a great help because I was programmatically inserting the nodes in `<databases> </databases>` in my web.config at run time and it was causing the cache to expire! A problem I could have avoided if I didn't act so extra! Follow-up: this was happening during App_Start while registering all modules and whatnot... Why does it affect the application at runtime and keep clearing the cache anyway?

Answer (score 5):

The Cache object doesn't guarantee that it will hold onto cached objects at all, much less for the full amount of time that you suggest.

If you want to more strongly encourage it to do so, you can set CacheItemPriority.High or CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable when you insert an item into the Cache.  With the default Normal priority, the runtime has a fairly aggressive policy of letting go of objects when memory pressure increases.

On top of that, by default the IIS AppPool will recycle once/day or so, which will clear everything in the Cache.

Answer (score 4):

The docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9.aspx say that Cache.NoSlidingExpiration must be used if using an absolute expiration.

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(CacheName, Price, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

this may not be your problem though, i just found that Cache.NoSlidingExpiration should be the same as TimeSpan.Zero.

Next i would check that your app pool isnt expiring and check how much cache you are using.  If it's a high traffic site using a lot of memory (ie memory cache) then it will expire cache items as the memory is needed for other things.

also check the last comment here http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/717129-c-asp-net-page-cache-getting-removed-too-soon  someone seems to have found a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the recycle time on your App Pool.

Answer (score 0):

By default, items added to the cache have no set expiration, so this is definitely something outside the cache. I agree with Josh, you should check the recycle time on your App Pool.

Check out this page to see an example of how you can add a delegate to let you know exactly when your item is being removed from the cache. This might help you in troubleshooting if it's not your App Pool:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx

~md5sum~