# C# HttpRuntime.Cache

Tags: c#, iis-7.5

I am on Win7 64-bit. This is a rather nasty problem. Here are the steps to reproduce it:

1. Create a new C# Asp.Net project in Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2010, not sure if this matters)
2. In the code behind for Default.aspx, add this code to the `Page_Load` method

   ```
   HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("foo", "test", null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0));

   string p = "var retval; retval = window.showModalDialog('Test.aspx','', 'dialogHeight:100px; dialogWidth: 100px;scroll: no;center: Yes; help: No; resizable: yes; status: no; unadorned: yes;');";
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "openpop", p, true);
   ```
3. Add another Web Form called Test.aspx. You can put whatever you want in the markup, it's not important.
4. In the code behind for Test.aspx, put this line in the `Page_Load` method, and set a breakpoint on it.

   ```
   string x = (string)HttpRuntime.Cache["foo"];
   ```
5. In the project properties, make sure application is set to run using local IIS Web Server.

When you run the project and it hits the breakpoint, step one more time to let it assign x, and then the value of x will be null. At least that's what's happening to me. I don't understand why this is happening, because the value should still be in the cache. In my real application, I also added a callback to HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert to track why the item was not in the cache, and it said it had expired. But if I gave it a 30 minute absolute expiration window, how can it be expired?

Interestingly enough, if you run the application using Visual Studio Development Server instead of IIS, the value is present in the cache!

Comment: Is this your answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792972/c-sharp-httpruntime-cache-insert-not-holding-cached-value

Comment: @Pete - No. As I mentioned, I added the callback to see why the item was being removed from the cache, but it said expired, which makes no sense since it has a 30 minute absolute expiration window.

Comment: Could it be a DST issue? Try using `DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)` instead.

Comment: I tried - everything is fine for me. IIS, Win7 x64, virtual application in default site

Comment: @Lanorkin - Interesting. I just tried it on a completely different machine on a separate network, but I have the same problem (e.g. a different machine made no difference for me).

Comment: @Richard Deeming - Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, no difference for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any issues with such setup, but you do. So I think the issue is in `DateTime.Now` setting you use. According to msdn:

> The time at which the inserted object expires and is removed from the cache. To avoid possible issues with local time such as changes from standard time to daylight saving time, use **UtcNow** rather than **Now** for this parameter value. If you are using absolute expiration, the slidingExpiration parameter must be NoSlidingExpiration.

So try this one:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("foo", "test", null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0));
```

Comment: Refer to my comments to Richard Deeming in the question above. It made no difference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Excelent :) @Lanorkin